# Does $ (a_{n}) = \sqrt{(4- (b_{n}) ^2} $, where $ (b_{n}) =\frac{1}{2}( 1+ \frac{1}{n}) ^{n} $ converge towards $ \sqrt{4- (e/2) ^2} $?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does $$ (a_{n}) = \sqrt{(4- (b_{n}) ^2} $$, where $$ (b_{n}) =\frac{1}{2}( 1+ \frac{1}{n}) ^{n} $$ converge towards $ \sqrt{4- (e/2) ^2} $?  Because $(b_{n})$ converges towards $\frac{e}{2}$?

Comment: Where do you get $e/2$?

Comment: Sorry I corrected it

Comment: Short answer: yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
$$\sqrt{4-b_n^2} = \sqrt{2 - b_n}\sqrt{2 + b_n}$$
then the limit is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} c^{-}_nc^{+}_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} c^{-}_n \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} c^{+}_n $$
we then have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} c^{\pm}_n = (\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\pm b_n)^{1/2}
$$
Then you can apply the limits.